# Is it possible to record simulated Steps data using Google Fit on Android emulator?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, google-fit

The package in question is: com.google.android.apps.fitness.

I'd like to record some fake steps data in the Android emulator and display it afterwards. I'm getting the sense that this is not possible.

I tried running version S with Google APIs installed as well as version 30 with Google Play installed and both times the com.google.android.apps.fitness package was unavailable.

My dependencies are as follows:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:18.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:20.0.0'
```

Please let me know if I'm missing dependencies or something else.

All help appreciated.

Comment: Hi, Google Fit is part of Google Play services. You should be able to simulate steps using an emulator with Google Play Services installed.